# $1 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2}$ What is $w$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the formula:

$$1 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2}$$

How to rewrite it to find $w$?

Comment: raise to the power of 2 move everything except $w^2$ on the left side and take the square root. If this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$w^2=1-(x^2+y^2+z^2)=w^2$$ so we obtain $$w=\pm\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$ for $$1\geq x^2+y^2+z^2$$

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Why do we have +/- there?

Comment: @noonespecial The standard convention is that the square root sign returns the positive value.  Since $w$ can be either positive or negative, we indicate this with the $\pm$ symbol.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  1 &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2} \\
  1 &= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 \\
  w^2 &= 1 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 \\
  w &= \pm\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Square the equation, move $x^2+y^2+z^2$ to the other side, then take the square root. Notice that you can take either the square root or the negative of that.